# Bulk update displayname attribute to match cn attribute for all AD groups

Tags: active-directory, adfs, microsoft-office-365

We are setting up ADFS for identity federation with a Microsoft Online service. The documentation states that "Groups without a displayname will NOT get synchronized..." We have over 250 groups that have a blank displayname attribute.

Does anyone know of a way to set the displayname attribute to match the cn attribute for all groups where the displayname is blank?

Comment: Could also use name or sAMAccountName attributes to update displayname.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the Microsoft Powershell commands you can do this.  You need to import the AD module if you do not have it already imported into your current powershell session.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties Displayname | Where-Object {$_.displayname -eq $null} | ForEach-Object {Set-ADGroup -Identity
$_ -DisplayName $_.SamaccountName}
```

Comment: Great.  Glad I could help.